# How do i select todays birthday date from SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, select

I'm trying to select all records from SQLite database where **birthday date is today.**

My table schema is as shown below.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+" (id integer primary key, name text, isactive integer default 0, bday text);");
}
```

I have tried to get the date by writting below query. But no use.

```
case 2:
    //Toast.makeText(context,"today called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      String query="select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where bday =strftime('%m',date('now','localtime')) and bday=strftime('%Y',date('now','localtime'))";
      cursor=database.rawQuery(query,null);
break;
```

I have parsed the user input date to store into the database in **'yyyy-MM-dd'** format. Help me to get todays birthday date from all records.

Comment: `bday` can never be equal to two different values at the same time like your query is doing...

Comment: And no reason to use `date()`... Just `strftime('format string', 'now', 'localtime')` is sufficient.

Comment: Ok. What i need to pass as format string? Is it valid strftime('%m-%d','now','localtime')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the rows of people whose birthday is today you should only be interested in the *month* and the *day* and **not** the *year*.
 
If the format of the column `bday` is `YYYY-MM-DD` then you need only the `MM-DD` part which you can get with:

```
substr(bday, 6)
```

Also you need the `MM-DD` part of today's date which you can get with:

```
strftime('%m-%d',date('now', 'localtime'))
```

So your WHERE clause should be:

```
where substr(bday, 6) = strftime('%m-%d',date('now', 'localtime'))
```

Comment: Thanks for exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a specific pattern( 'yyyy-MM-dd') to save birth date, it is easy to find users by birth day. Let me  describing in few steps.

1. Collect current date programatically and substring it, only take month and date from the current date.

   ```
   String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

   String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()); //2020-01-27
   String birthdaySubString= date.substring(5, 10); //01-27
   ```
2. Call your database handler method with birthDaySubString.

   ```
       getUserbyBirthDay(birthdaySubString);
   ```
3. From the handler method query your database with 'like' operator and use this birthDaySubString to search.

   `public List<user> getUserbyBirthDay(String birthdaySubString){
       //select * from user where bday like "%08-17";

       String query="select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where bday like "+birthdaySubString+"'";
       cursor=database.rawQuery(query,null);

   }`

It should work. It is tested in sqliteBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Select * from Table
where strftime('%m-%d',birthdate) = strftime('%m-%d',date('now', 'localtime'))
```